# ansible shell: how to show grep result the same as run at local

Tags: shell, ansible

```
- name: check process is running or not
  shell: ps -ef |grep abcd |grep defg
  register: result
  ignore_errors: yes
- debug: msg="{{ result.stdout }}"
```

the result shows:

```
TASK [debug] ***********
ok: [52.35.61.9] => {
"msg": "ec2-user 28932 28931  0 17:42 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c ps 
-ef |grep abcd |grep defg"
}
```

but if I login to that machine and directly run:

```
ps -ef |grep abcd |grep defg,
```

I see nothing because the process has stopped.

in ansible I need to check whether the process is already run. and then run it only if it is not. That is why I use shell and ps (command does not support pipe so I have to use shell) . but calling shell from ansible always shows sth. even the process is not run.

how to make it not show anything, same as when run ps locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing a character in square brackets like this:

```
shell: ps -ef |grep [a]bcd |grep defg
```

This is just to make `grep` ignore that line in `ps` output.